# How is "Jerusalem" pronounced when reading a Ketubah?

Tags: wedding, eretz-yisrael, hebrew

"Jerusalem" is spelled the same way in Hebrew and Aramaic (if you ignore the vowels); but in Hebrew it's pronounced "Yerushalayim", and in Aramaic it's pronounced "Yerushleim" (as it appears in the Akdamut.)

The text of the Ketubah is primarily Aramaic; so when reading a Ketubah in Jerusalem, do you pronounce the city's name the Hebrew way (as we're used to) or the Aramaic way?  And why?

Comment: If anyone know a source for a transliterated ketubah or a ketubah with nekudot, (or myaybe an audio file somewhere?)

Comment: @michaelpariser, Welcome to Judaism.SE! Please consider [posting](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) your question as an actual question on the main site and then checking back for answers.

Comment: If this question interested you, remember to join the [Hebrew Language and Usage beta-site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage?referrer=vYF-uD8pJWlpaSf89lZ05w2) in the StackExchange network

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing why this matters.

Comment: @DoubleAA more than you think -- I heard an mp3 from R' Hershel Schachter shlit'a -- can a ketubah be in a mix of two languages? Half in Hebrew half in English? Because the standard text we use is a mix of Hebrew and Aramaic! No, that's a language called "rabbinic."

Comment: @Shalom But as you said, it's spelled the same way in both languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked Rabbi Yitzchak Breitowitz; he said as everyone calls it Yerushalayim, that's how it's pronounced (the Hebrew way).

Comment: What does R' J. David Bleich say? You've told me before of his prescriptivist leanings in these matters.