# Spelling ירושלים as ירושלם

Tags: words, prayer-book, yerushalayim-jerusalem

In almost all cases, I have seen the word "Yerushalayim" spelled like this: יְרוּשָׁלַיִם. However, sometimes I have seen it spelled like this: יְרוּשָׁלִַם, missing a י between the ל and the ם. Is this just a misspelling, or is this really a true variation?

[Note: This "misspelling" is made in my Siddur Tehillas Hashem and my Machzor Hasholeim from Kehot. Both are all-Hebrew. Pictures are provided here for ease of access. I also remember seeing this spelling in the Stone Tanach somewhere in Psalms, but I cannot find it again.]

[image: Virushaloyim irecho berachamim toshuv]

Comment: Related: [Extra yud in Yerushalaim](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14852/extra-yud-in-yerushalaim) and [Ḥaser form of writing “Jerusalem” in the Bible](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3791/%e1%b8%a4aser-form-of-writing-jerusalem-in-the-bible/3792#3792)

Comment: @Rish - Boruch Hashem, this is exactly what I was looking for. A hartsign dank tsu dir.